# Can one use reactjs without writing any class?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, react-hooks

I am wondering, if classes are just syntax sugar for prototypes, and es6 enhances functional coding, can we write reactJS code purely functionally(and without missing out on lifecycle methods)?

[edit]

Think of the most complex react app, can that be written purely functionally - and would it make sense to do that?

EDIT 2019 May:
React Hooks is here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 classes are syntactic sugar for functions and (with some exceptions) it's possible to rewrite them as functions, this is what transpilers like Babel and TypeScript do.

Since component class inherits from `React.Component`, it needs to prototypically inherit from it. `React.Component` doesn't have static properties, so a component doesn't need to inherit them.

This component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { name: 'foo' };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ name: 'bar'});
  }

  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.name}</p>;
  }
}
```

becomes

```
function App(props) {
  React.Component.call(this, props);
  this.state = { name: 'foo' };
}

App.prototype = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);
App.prototype.constructor = App;

App.prototype.componentDidMount = function () {
  this.setState({ name: 'bar'});
};

App.prototype.render = function () {
  return React.createElement('p', null, this.state.name);
};
```

This is what now-deprecated `React.createClass` originally did, `create-react-class` helper [serves this purpose](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html).

> if classes are just syntax sugar for prototypes, and es6 enhances functional coding, can we write reactJS code purely functionally(and without missing out on lifecycle methods)?

We can, but functional component isn't the same thing as a component written with desugared JavaScript class. [Functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) is specific React term that refers to *stateless* functional component. Stateless components don't have a state and lifecycle hooks. It's impossible, or at least impractical, to write real React application with stateless components alone.

> Think of the most complex react app, can that be written purely functionally - and would it make sense to do that?

Deliberate avoidance of ES6 class syntax doesn't make sense in general because the lack of syntactic sugar results in verbose and unexpressive code without any benefits. A regular React application still needs to use build step and Babel to transpile JSX syntax because desugared JSX is a hierarchy of verbose `React.createElement` calls. It is practical only if few React components are used in non-React ES5 application that doesn't need build step to be introduced.

However, this may be possible with third-party libraries, e.g. `recompose`. It's intended to be used with functional components, e.g. [`lifecycle`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle) helper allows to attach lifecycle hooks to them. Of course, it uses component class internally to do that.

Comment: thanks @estus, makes more sense now -  "Deliberate avoidance of ES6 class syntax doesn't make sense in general because the lack of syntactic sugar results is verbose and unexpressive"

Comment: this is actual answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use stateless component

This article explain

https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc

example: for stateless component

```
import React from ‘react’;

const HelloWorld = ({name}) => (
 <div>{`Hi ${name}`}</div>
);

export default HelloWorld;
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**  : 
my example lacks lifecycle methods implemented by @estus,so if you don't need those lifecycle methods than you can use below code

Yes you can

```
import React from ‘react’;

function MyComponent(){
 return <div>Hello</div>
}

export default MyComponent;
```

[Live Example](https://codepen.io/pawarvijay/pen/EeWQmQ)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a way of doing stuff. React gives us two types of components. We use them for a particular purpose.Not everything could be written in stateless components (functions). Stateless components are usually presentation components which only render jsx and have no local state. We can't write methods in stateless components and here comes the Stateful components (class based) where we manage our own state and write methods into it. Further it gives us more control to render our child components. So everything in react follows a pattern and it allows to utilize the power of one way binding.